# How to trigger a sequence of (automatic) segues with identifiers from code

Tags: ios, swift, segue

Using a homescreen quick action, my quick action deep links to the 3rd VC in my nav stack.  I can get to the 2nd VC via the below, but I need to trigger another performSegueWithIdentifer...is it possible since I don't have a reference to call it on?

```
 case ShortCutIdentifier.Second.type:
                handled = true

                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let navVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("peopleNavController") as! UINavigationController
                let peopleTVC = navVC.topViewController as! PeopleTableViewController
                self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(navVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

                peopleTVC.performSegueWithIdentifier("showStoresSegue", sender: peopleTVC)

                //I want to perform segue again here but from what object?
```

Comment: Set some kind of flags in the second view controller and when second view controller has just shown call the third view controller according the the flag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example solution to get a second segue to be performed after the first.

In your first view controller, add the following:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showStoresSegue" {
        segue.destinationViewController.someSegueShouldHappen = true
    }
}
```

Then, in your second view controller, add:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear()

    if someSegueShouldHappen {
        yourSecondViewController.performSegueWithIdentifier(“The Second Segue”, sender: self)
        someSegueShouldHappen = false
    }
}
```

You’ll need to add a property named `someSegueShouldHappen` or a name of your choice on your second view controller as in

```
var someSegueShouldHappen: Bool = false
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was thinking as well as per Jason's comment...i need to differentiate in VC#3 whether you got here "organically" i.e. the user paged through the app or whether you were segued here from the home screen short cut...I think I can set the flag/bool from the app delegate to make this distinction

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad my answer could be understood and you also have a good sense of how to handle the different states in your app.